# Firebase Login feature not working in deployed Next js app but works fine in local environment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, firebase-authentication, vercel, railway

I have created a next js app with firebase Google login feature, it works absolutely fine in my local environment but when I deployed it on Railway and Vercel the Login feature is not working, as the user clicks on the login button it doesn't show the pop-up window.

Does it has to do anything with PORT number? Like I saw some of the answers where someone told env.PORT || 3000, can someone please elaborate the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your domain to the list of the authorized domains in the Firebase Auth. See:
[image]

Comment: I think he also has to allow pop-ups on browser

Answer (score 1):

Two things have worked for me.

1. Set the authorised domain in Firebase (Authentication > Settings > Authorised domains)
2. Remove the "" from the environment variables in Vercel. (Vercel > Your project > Settings > Environment Variables). Click and edit each firebase variable and remove the "".